# Can't connect to my Bluemix container (Connection: close)

Tags: docker, containers, command-line-interface, ibm-cloud

Hello everybody and happy new year,

I have some issues connecting to my bluemix container,
I followed this [IBM's Bluemix guide](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_gettingstarted_tutorial.html#container_gettingstarted_tutorial) 
to learn how to pull a docker image to bluemix image repository, which works.

Then I executed the command to open port 9080 server side (the vm one is 5000 according to my Dockerfile)

PS: ((I have tried with -P instead of -p 9080 or -p 9080:5000 but none works in fixing this issue))

```
cf ic -v run -d -p 9080 --name testdebug registry.ng.bluemix.net/datainjector/esolom python testGUI.py
```

after a "cf ic ps" I obtain:

```
CONTAINER ID      IMAGE       
8457d4bb-247      registry.ng.bluemix.net/datainjector/esolom:latest 

COMMAND                 PORTS          NAMES  
"python testGUI.py "    9080/tcp      testdebug
```

the debug command (executed while running the image) reports me this:

```
DEMANDE : [2017-01-12T11:57:42+01:00]
POST /UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.ng.bluemix.net
Accept: application/json
Authorization: [DONNEES PRIVEES MASQUEES]
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: go-cli 6.22.2+a95e24c / darwin

grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.PIQlkKPDwxfa0c6951pO52qcAzggfPGrsCMuFl4V-eY&scope=

REPONSE : [2017-01-12T11:57:42+01:00]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate,no-store
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' www.ibm.com 'unsafe-inline';
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 10:57:42 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache,no-cache
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Archived-Client-Ip: 169.54.180.83
X-Backside-Transport: OK OK,OK OK
X-Client-Ip: 169.54.180.83,91.151.65.169
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Global-Transaction-Id: 3429006079
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1
X-Vcap-Request-Id: 8990fd56-827c-4956-696d-497922464ac0,04094b44-0ace-    4891-6ec0-c4855fd481f7
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

6f6
{"access_token":"[DONNEES PRIVEES MASQUEES]","token_type":"[DONNEES PRIVEES MASQUEES]","refresh_token":"[DONNEES PRIVEES MASQUEES]","expires_in":1209599,"scope":"cloud_controller.read password.write cloud_controller.write openid uaa.user","jti":"9619d1dd-995f-41b4-8a8a-825af8397ccb"}
0


ae4b3e08-4ba6-47d9-bf1f-30654af7fcfc
```

Next I bind an IP I requested with:

```
cf ic ip request // 169.46.18.243 was given
cf ic ip bind 169.46.18.243 testdebug
OK
The IP address was bound successfully.
```

And the "cf ic ps" command gave me this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 
1afd6916-718        registry.ng.bluemix.net/datainjector/esolom:latest

COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                  
 "python testGUI.py "   5 minutes ago       Running 5 minutes ago

PORTS                          NAMES
169.46.18.243:9080->9080/tcp   testdebug
```

Associated logs:

```
 cf ic logs -ft testdebug
 2017-01-12T12:45:54.531512850Z /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:334: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
 32017-01-12T12:45:54.531555759Z   SNIMissingWarning
 �2017-01-12T12:45:54.531568916Z /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:132: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
 92017-01-12T12:45:54.531576871Z   InsecurePlatformWarning
 �2017-01-12T12:45:54.836875400Z /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:132: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
 92017-01-12T12:45:54.836895214Z   InsecurePlatformWarning
 �2017-01-12T12:45:54.884966459Z WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent and gevent-websocket for improved performance.
 Y2017-01-12T12:45:54.889150620Z  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

So, is the fact that the same ports are attributed to host and VM are responsible for "connection: close" in the debug log? or are those two different problems?

Is "connection: close" explains that I can't connect to the web app?

Do you have an idea of how to fix this? (something to fix in the image? or an additional option in the CLI?)

Thank you for reading, your commitment and for your answers!

PS: 
Clues: I'm looking for modifying the Dockerfile, I read that I have to had 2 instructions in order to integrate my docker image to Bluemix, a sleep command so that I'm sure the container is up before calling him, and apparently the "ENV PORT 3000" instruction, here is my Dockerfile, don't hesitate to review it, a simple error easily happens.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python2.7
RUN apt-get -y install python-pip
RUN pip install Flask
RUN pip install ibmiotf
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install flask-socketio
RUN pip install cloudant
ENV PORT=3000
EXPOSE 3000
ADD ./SIARA /opt/SIARA/
WORKDIR /opt/SIARA/
CMD (sleep 60)
CMD ["python", "testGUI.py"]
```

Comment: Be careful. There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect. But you can concatenate more commands in a single CMD.

Comment: Oh ok it's good to know @gile
Considering this, If I let the CMD (sleep 60) can I still execute:

cf ic run --options image python testGUI.py ? or it will lead to a conflict?
The IBM container CLI don't provide this much info about the success or fail of the commands :/

Comment: The command issued by docker run overrides the CMD in Dockerfile. To run both your commands, you can change Dockerfile, e.g. CMD sleep 60; python testGUI.py

Comment: @gile I did write something like CMD sleep 60 && python testGUI.py.

For no reason, I tried again later in the afternoon (I changed nothing lol) and it works *sigh* bluemix in a nutshell!
Thank you for your tips considerably helped me in solving this :)

Answer (score 0):

changed the Dockerfile for:

```
CMD sleep 60 && python testGUI.py
```

after seeing the @gile comment.

Even if it didn't works immediately, after 3 hours it works surprisingly well!

EDIT: seems it was just a lucky shot, I can't access to the container again, my idea is that it worked because my dockerHub rebuilt the image after commiting the changes on the Dockerfile because it worked just after I copied the images from dockerhub repo to bluemix private repo.

Does it highlight an issue? Because I don't understand why it didn't worked from again...